# How to intercept/catch a subscription error on cometd 2.x

Tags: java, web, cometd

I need to develop code to intercept cometd subscription errors on the server side. I checked the documentation and found out the BayeuxServer.SubscriptionListener, nevertheless it is just a listener for the subscription/unsubscription events. Going further and checking cometd 2.x sources I can't find some kind of exception being thrown for this kind of event.

Is there anyway of doing that?

Comment: You need to be a lot more precise about what you mean by "subscription error". CometD does not fail any subscription, unless the application told CometD to do so, for example when a user does not have the permission to subscribe.
Therefore, any "subscription error" is an application error, and you need to intercept those in your application, not in CometD.

Comment: Subscription errors are errors during subscriptions. I did my workaround using the security policy cannot subscribe. Thank you!